# Magento 2: Modal video in product list

Tags: magento2, product-list, modal-popup, product-video

**In the product list, I want to check if product video exists show button video**

> `like this:`

[image]

and when `I click` on the `button video` will be played like `modal`.

Any way to `solve it`? 
**Thank in advance.**